# a manifold is regular

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification, manifolds

I want to prove a manifold is regular and i've done something but i want to check it:
Let $X$ a manifold, $x\in X, U_x$ open neighborhood of $x$. Let $y\neq x, y\in U_x$. Since $X$ is Hausdorff,so it is $U_x$. Then $\exists W_y, W_x\subset U_x$ open sets(here do we use the hypothesis of being locally euclidean?) s.t $W_y\cap W_x=\emptyset$. Then $x\in W_x\subseteq U_x\setminus W_y\subset U_x$. But, $U_x\setminus W_y$ is a close set that contains $W_x$ then $\overline{W_x}\subset U_x\setminus W_y\subset U$. Thus X is regular.

P.d I know an alternative proof using only definitions and properties, so no equations are needed but i want to focus on my solution.

Comment: When stating the existence of $W_y$ and $W_x$, you do not use the hypothesis of being locally Euclidean, you're just using the fact $X$ is Hausdorff. However, I'm unsure where your proof is going. Being regular means "for any $x \in X$, and any closed set $C$ s.t $x \notin C$, there exists open sets around $x$ and $C$ that do not intersect. You should be starting with $x$ and $C$, and then looking for open sets. In your proof, you are starting with $x$, then you produce some closed set which contains a closed neighborhood of $x$. Unless I'm missing something, I don't think that's the way to go

Comment: i'm using that a space X is regular iff $\forall x\in X$ and $U_x$ there exists a neighborhood $V$of $x$ such that $\overline{V}\subset U$. This is munkres, lemma 31.1

Comment: My big question here is in which part of my proof is the locally euclidean condition applied?

Comment: There is absolutely no reason, why $U_x \setminus W_y$ should be closed. If it were, then you would have "proven" that every Hausdorff space is regular.